# Bootstrap 4 - SASS extending button not working on anchor tag?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I like the style of the default buttons from pre-Bootstrap 4. In order to try to make my own I came up with the following SASS:

```
.btn-default {
    @extend .btn;
    border-color: #A5A5A5;
}

.btn.btn-default:hover,
.btn.btn-default:focus,
.btn.btn-default:active,
.btn.btn-default.active {
    color: #808080;
}
```

This works as expected if I used a `<button>` tag but not if I use a `<a>` tag. Why wouldn't this work on both?

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
    Test Anchor
</a>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
    Test Button
</button>
```

[image]

Why would this not work on the anchor tag when you can normally assign a .btn class to an anchor tag and it will style it like a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to @extend `.btn` since you're already using `.btn`.

All the other `btn-*` variations have a `color`, `background-color` and `border-color`, so in CSS you could create a `btn-default` with:

```
.btn-default{
   color:#333;
   background-color:#bbb;
   border-color:#a5a5a5
 }
.btn.btn-default:hover,
.btn.btn-default:focus,
.btn.btn-default:active,
.btn.btn-default.active {
    color: #808080;
}
```

The Bootstrap SASS way would be to use the button-variant @mixin...

```
.btn-default {
    @include button-variant(#bbb, #a5a5a5, #bbb, darken(#bbb, 10%), darken(#bbb, 10%), darken(#bbb, 12.5%))
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/CWJidmeI1D

Here are the params for the button-variant mixin:

```
button-variant($background, $border, $hover-background, $hover-border, $active-background, $active-border)
```

Comment: Thanks! The CSS works as expected. I'm still new with SASS and would prefer that way. Tried this SASS and it's only missing the hoover effect. I'll try to research and play around with the @mixin to see if I can get it to have the hoover as well.

Comment: YW! Yes, the 3rd param controls that so you can change it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` tag doesn't have the behavior  of a button. Inorder make it try the following code

```
a.btn{
 -webkit-appearance: button;
 -moz-appearance: button;
 appearance: button;

 text-decoration: none;
 color: initial;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me closer. The only thing missing is the border-radius. I tried adding it and then setting it to $btn-border-radius which didn't work. Then lookup up Bootstrap button radius and tried setting mine to the .25rem but that didn't work either. Do you know of a way to set the border radius on an anchor tag?

Comment: Bootstrap button has default border-radius. If you want to over ride it be more specific in your class and override the bootstrap css

Comment: I'm not trying to over ride the Bootstrap button, I'm trying to get the CSS that you included above for the anchor tag to look like a button. The only thing missing in the above code is a border-radius. I tried adding border-radius: .25rem; with the code above but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Make it `!important` and check

Comment: Nope. No go. I also just read where it doesn't work in IE. I ended up altering Bootstrap's button-secondary color and it looks like that works on both a button and anchor...go figure.